# SQL join with case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I modify the join clause with a case clause; for example I want the table to join another column if column1 is null such as:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
LEFT JOIN OTHERTABLE ON 
CASE WHEN MYTABLE.A IS NULL THEN MYTABLE.B = OTHERTABLE.A
ELSE MYTABLE.A IS NOT NULL THEN MYTABLE.A = OTHERTABLE.A
```

(totally made that up,sorry for syntax errors :))

Comment: Is the `IS NULL` test the one you're actually trying to solve, or just an example? - As you can see from the answers so far, NULL doesn't need a case statement at all.

Comment: actually it could be anything so its not null specific.

Comment: CASE ... END statement always returns a value, which you can use in joins or comparisons. You can't use any joins or other conditions inside a CASE statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable M
LEFT JOIN OtherTable O ON(CASE WHEN M.A IS NULL THEN M.B ELSE M.A END) = O.A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
LEFT JOIN OTHERTABLE ON COALESCE(MYTABLE.A, MYTABLE.B) = OTHERTABLE.A
```

Comment: Your answer handles the specific example, but doesn't answer the actual question - the question is about incorporating a `CASE` statement into a `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Just try below code :

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
LEFT JOIN OTHERTABLE ON OTHERTABLE.A = isnull(MYTABLE.A,MYTABLE.B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isnull() or coalesce() to check the null value.